# Simple Button in javascript isn't working, tried hosts of things, not sure why

Tags: button, console

Now first, i'm not even sure if you can do this; but with my limited knowledge of functions, I wanted to create a button that will display both an object in the console and on the document. I figured, it would be easier to try to run in the console first but, I just keep getting an error: [button help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjuwD.png)

So basically, can i run a simple function in both the console and in the document with simple button, and how would i tailor my code here to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, it cannot find your function. Add this to your code:

```
<button onclick="window.displayState()">
```

And this in your js:

```
window.displayState = function() {
   console.log("here");
};
```